# Проверьте, пожалуйста, ответы на тесты по риторике

Tags: стилистика, риторика

1. Текст «Пенсионный фонд – это дойная корова, на молоко которой рассчитывают сейчас и правительство, и регионы» построен на использовании…
   А)олицетворения.
   **Б) метафоры.**
   В) метонимии.
   Г) слов в прямом значении.
2. Во фрагменте текста «При мне Толька тоже приезжал. На мотоцикле» используется такое средство выразительности, как…
   А) метонимия.
   Б) синтаксический параллелизм.
   В) перифраз.
   **Г) парцелляция.**
3. Текст «Я царь, я раб, я червь, я Бог» построен на использовании…
   **А) градации.**
   Б) антитезы.
   В) инверсии.
   Г) умолчания.
4. Текст «Я обратился к Егору Тимуровичу: мы закупали хлеб. Дай денег. Дай денег, отец родной! Дай хоть копеечку!» построен на использовании…
   **А) иронии.**
   Б) литоты.
   В) метафоры.
   Г) олицетворения.
5. Текст «Люблю я пышное природы увяданье» построен на использовании…
   А) метафоры.
   **Б) оксюморона.**
   В) гиперболы.
   Г) иронии.
6. В риторике выделяют несколько видов красноречия. 
   Определите лишние: 
   А) академическое; 
   Б) судебное; 
   В) социально-политическое; 
   Г) социально-бытовое; 
   **Д) театральное;** 
   Е) духовное (церковно-богословское); 
   **Ж) доклад.**
7. Судебная речь является разновидностью … речи.
   •   информационной.
   •   агитационной.
   **• протокольно-этикетной.**
   •   аргументирующей.
8. К жанру академического красноречия НЕ относится…
   А) лекция вузовская, школьная;
   **Б) приветственное слово;**
   В) научный доклад;
   Г) научный обзор; 
   Д) научное сообщение; 
   Е) научно-популярная лекция; 
   **Ж) агитаторское выступление**
9. К жанру социально-бытового красноречия относится…
   А) выступление на митингах.
   **Б) приветственная речь.**
   В) научное сообщение.
   **Г) поминальная речь.**
10. К жанру академического красноречия НЕ относится…
    А) лекция вузовская, школьная.
    **Б) приветственное слово.**
    В) научный доклад.
    **Г) агитаторское выступление.**
11. К жанру социально-бытового красноречии НЕ относится…
    А) приветственная речь.
    Б) юбилейная речь.
    В) застольная речь.
    **Г) дипломатическая речь.**
12. К жанру духовного (церковно-богословского) красноречия относится…
    **А) проповедь.**
    Б) учебная лекция.
    В) юбилейная речь.
    Г) выступления на социально-политические темы.
13. К основным родам красноречия не относится…
    А) судебное.
    Б) социально-политическое.
    **В) административно-правовое.**
    Г) духовное (церковно-богословское).
14. Мешает установлению контакта с аудиторией при публичном выступлении…
    А) учет особенностей аудитории.
    **Б) затянутое вступление.**
    В) уверенность оратора.
    Г) авторитет личности оратора.
15. Под коммуникативным равновесием в риторике понимают…
    **А) отведение собеседнику в процессе общения роли не ниже той, которая обусловлена его социальной ролью и представлением о его собственном достоинстве.**
    Б) знание законов общения.
    В) достижение говорящим поставленной цели.
    Г) трудности в общении, возникающие как у выступающего, так и у слушателей.
16. Принцип кооперации состоит из нескольких максим (правил). Укажите, какая из максим приведена: Избегайте двусмысленности и неопределенности, говорите коротко и упорядоченно.
    **А) Максима способа выражения.**
    Б) Максима качества.
    В) Максима количества.
    Г) Максима релевалентности.
17. Принцип вежливости состоит из нескольких максим (правил). Укажите максиму, не входящую в этот принцип.
    **А) Максима способа выражения.**
    Б) Максима одобрения.
    В) Максима такта.
    Г) Максима великодушия.
18. Принцип вежливости состоит из нескольких максим (правил). Укажите, какая это максима: Максима границ личной сферы. В идеале любой коммуникативный акт предусматривает определенную дистанцию. Не следует затрагивать тем, потенциально опасных (частная жизнь, индивидуальные предпочтения и пр.).
    А) Максима симпатии.
    **Б) Максима такта.**
    В) Максима великодушия.
    Г) Максима одобрения.
19. Принцип вежливости состоит из нескольких максим (правил). Укажите, какая это максима: Успешный коммуникативный акт не должен быть дискомфортным для участников общения. Не следует связывать партнера обещанием или клятвой.
    А) Максима одобрения.
    Б) Максима согласия.
    **В) Максима великодушия.**
    Г) Максима скромности.
20. Принцип вежливости состоит из нескольких максим (правил). Укажите, какая это максима: Позитивность в оценке других («не судите, да не судимы будете»; «не осуждай других»).
    **А) Максима одобрения.**
    Б) Максима согласия.
    В) Максима великодушия.
    Г) Максима скромности.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока вижу две ошибки:

3. Текст «Я царь, я раб, я червь, я Бог» построен на использовании…

А) градации.-неверно.

Б) верно  **антитезы.** царь-раб, червь -Бог

4.Текст «Я обратился к Егору Тимуровичу: мы закупали хлеб. Дай денег. Дай денег, отец родной! Дай хоть копеечку!» построен на использовании…
А) иронии.
Б) литоты.
В) метафоры.
Г) олицетворения.

Иронии не вижу. Вижу литоту - хоть копеечку - явное преуменьшение.